# If I want to force users deriving an Interface to implement a private method/property, is there some trick?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, access-modifiers

If I want to force users deriving an Interface to implement a private method, is there some trick?

It seems as though I should be able to do something to the effect of:

```
namespace cc
{
    interface Icd
    {
        int one { get; private set; }
        int two { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

I understand why this won't work, an interface after all is the guaranteed public front end for objects derived from it, however, there must be a way to force coders implementing my interface to have to implement the setter privately.

Would an abstract class work in this case? I don't want to define code, just force whoever implements my interface to implement a private setter for properties.

**Edit:** Yes, this is C# :-)

Comment: Is this C#?  We might be able to come up with a super-klugey language-specific 'solution' if we knew what language.

Comment: Yeah, C#, sorry should have specified that

Comment: On second thought, what's the use case here?  An interface has no code, and anyone using the interface can't call a private method.  How is this different from simply omitting `set`?

Comment: @Ken: To force the proeprty to be read-only.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I just didn't think this through correctly before asking.

Comment: @SLaks: You can define a read-only property in the interface, e.g. `int one { get; }`.  Then a setter is not required at all.

Comment: @Ben: But then an implementer can add a setter.

Comment: @SLaks: Interesting, but references to the interface type would already have read-only properties. This would only serve to force implementations to have read-only properties as well. I'm not sure I like the idea of interfaces enforcing a specific implementation...

Comment: @SLaks: Only by implementing the interface property explicitly and implementing a `new` property with get and set, and you could still do that even if the `private set;` syntax were allowed.

Comment: @Ben: Wrong.  A simple writable property can implement a readonly one.  Try it.

Comment: @SLaks: Hmmm.  I must have been thinking of overriding a virtual property, in which case you can't add an accessor (e.g. http://ideone.com/nv5pO).  My point about being able to add the setter through explicit interface implementation still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control the implementation of the property.  Period.  Forcing them to make the setter private doesn't make sense, no consumer of the interface could ever call it.  No point in declaring a setter that nobody can call anyway, might as well omit it.  Now it *does* work, there is no setter to call.  That's pretty private.

Answer (score 3):

Use an abstract base class instead of an interface:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract int MyProperty { get; protected set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's private, it seems like what you're really interested in controlling is some intra-company code-writing conventions or something like that. Maybe what you really want to be looking at is something from your version control software that would reject commits that don't follow the rules?